# dsl for capturing field name

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm working on a mapper and wanted a typesafe way to capture class fieldnames for mapping and went with a syntax I'd used in C#:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

new Mapping[Person]() { 
  field(_.age).name("person_age").colType[java.lang.Integer]
  field(_.name).name("person_name")
}
```

where `def field(m: T => Unit): FieldMap`

This triggers the following warnings:

```
Warning:(97, 13) a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
field(_.age).name("person_age").colType[java.lang.Integer]
        ^
Warning:(98, 13) a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
field(_.name).name("person_name")
        ^
```

So clearly that's not a desirable syntax. Any way I can tweak the signature of `field` to avoid the warning or is there a more idiomatic scala way of mapping fields in a typesafe manner?

**Note:** @sjrd's answer indeed gets rid of the warning, but the attempted feature doesn't seem feasible with scala reflection after all. My end goal is a Mapper that allows the specifying of `T` members in a compile time checked mannner, rather than strings, so it's less vulnerable to typo's and refactoring issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `field` method takes a `T => Unit` function as parameter. Hence, the lambda `_.age`, which is equivalent to `x => x.age`, is typechecked as returning `Unit`. The compiler warns that you are using a pure expression (`x.age`) in statement position (expected type `Unit`), which basically means that the expression is useless, and might as well be removed.

There is a very simple symptomatic solution to your problem: replace `m: T => Unit` by `m: T => Any`. Now your expression `x.age` is not in statement position anymore, and the compiler is happy.

But your code suggests that there is something wrong a little bit deeper, since you obviously don't use the result of `m` anywhere. Why is `m` for anyway?

Comment: That does solve the warning. However the C# trick i was trying to replicate won't work after all. The reason `field` never does anything with `m` was that it was supposed to only exist for the side-effect of specifying members of `T` in a compile-checked manner and then the referenced field is picked out via reflection for the mapping. In C# `T => Any` would have been an Expression to be inspected. Don't see that working via scala's reflection :(

Comment: Maybe you want macros? Macros can inspect the trees (equivalent to `Expression`, I suppose) of their application.

Comment: Been looking at macros, after seeing Slick's Direct Embedding. Looks like that's the better way to go and faster than reflection as well. thx.